# how to compare a hash key of a one file with a hash value of another in perl

Tags: perl

I have two files. one file only contains key and another has key and value both. how could i compare a key of one file with value of another?

```
  example of file1 
  steve
  robert
  sandy
  alex

  example of file2
  age25, steve
  age29, alex
  age30, mindy
  age50, rokuna
  age25, steve

  example of output
  age25, steve
  age29, alex
```

Here is what i have so far

```
    my $age_name="file1.txt";
    my $name="file2.txt";
    open my  $MYFILE, "<", $name or die "could not open $name \n";
    open my  $MYFILE2, "<", $age_name or die "could not open $age_name \n";
    while(<$MYFILE>) {
    my ($key, $value) = split(",");
    my $secondfile = <$MYFILE2>;

    if ( defined $secondfile ) {
        my ($key2, $value2) = split(","); 
        if ($value2=~m/$key/) {
        print "$key2 - $value2 \n";
        }
    }

    }
    close $MYFILE;
    close $MYFILE2;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are reading one line from the first file and one line from the second line. The problem is the lines do not have to be related. The classical solution is to read one file into a hash and then use the hash for lookup while reading the second one:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my %age_of;
open my $AGE, '<', 'file2.txt' or die $!;
while (<$AGE>) {
    chomp;
    my ($age, $name) = split /, /;
    $age_of{$name} = $age;
}

open my $NAME, '<', 'file1.txt' or die $!;
while (<$NAME>) {
    chomp;
    print "$age_of{$_}, $_\n" if exists $age_of{$_};
}
```

Comment: Hey Thanks for your help. i am getting a grip now :)